# Laravel - sending recovery mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to send a recovery mail using Laravel. I have the following recovery method:

```
public function recovery(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->only('email'), [
            'email' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationHttpException($validator->errors()->all());
        }

        $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject(Config::get('boilerplate.recovery_email_subject'));
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return $this->response->noContent();
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return $this->response->errorNotFound();
        }
    }
```

I tried to output `$request->email` and the reset email is the output, but for some reasons I get the following error:

```
Undefined index: email

at
"/home/pokemoti/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrokerManager.php" on line 74
```

Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: is there a reason why you don't use the build in solution to recover the password?

Comment: No reason, I am having this version of laravel for a while with different built-in auth for jwt tokens, I have no idea how I can use the build in solution in this case

Comment: you can always spin up a new testing laravel-project and run `php artisan make:auth` and take a look at how the reset is handled there In that case you don't mess up your current project.

Comment: try this 

Password::sendResetLink(['email'=>$request->only('email')], function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject(Config::get('boilerplate.recovery_email_subject'));

Comment: @Christophvh the make:auth creating only blade templates for me, not an actual controller, I'm using Laravel 5.2

Comment: @Rodrane same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the following line in my `config/auth.php` passwords->users array:

```
'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
```

took it from another project where it worked.